# How to delete lots of rows from PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, query-optimization, amazon-rds

We have a table with lots of rows (100m) hosted in AWS RDS.

1. How can we efficiently delete 50% of rows if the table has constant read, write and update queries?
2. How to delete 1% of data on daily basis?

Table structure:

- created_at
- user_id
- other data

We tried deleting day by day, but then autovacuum started and queue depth grew.

Comment: [Partition the table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html) and remove the "oldest" partition when needed.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the table structure to the question. I need to query all data for the user for all time. Am I able to achieve this with partitioning? Also, I have this table right now and I'm not able to add partitioning for current data, but only for new data.

Comment: If your system cannot handle an autovacuum, then it is either misconfigured or underprovisioned.  Regardless of what triggered the autovacuum.

Comment: @jjanes or it has a lot of data and a lot of traffic. 100M rows is a lot of data. If you follow the link to the partitioning docs you'll see that one of the primary benefits is that it avoids vacuuming.If you detach a partition instead of dropping it, there's almost no downtime or blocking because this is essentially a metadata operation.

Comment: The [AWS announcement for Postgres 11](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/diving-into-new-functionality-for-postgresql-11/) on Postgres RDS partitioning is a nice short tutorial on partitioning and its benefits in general. The [announcement for Postgres 12](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/postgresql-12-a-deep-dive-into-some-new-functionality/) explains how partition pruning (avoiding irrelevant partitions when running a query) was improved in the latest release.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  Sure, but how can he get from the current starting point to having it be partitioned, if we doesn't even have enough IO capacity to support an autovac?  He will need to get the data into their intended partitions somehow.  And even partitioned, he probably needs vacuuming anyway as he says there are constant updates.

Comment: @jjames partitioning exists because *no* database server has the capacity to autovac once the data gets big enough without impacting performance. A 100ms delay is far better than a 100s or a 60m freeze. The problem isn't vacuuming in general, it's vacuuming 10M rows without impacting the application. Which is what partitions are for.

Comment: @jjames As for partitioning an existing table, that's a big one-off maintenance operation. All systems have such operations.  With an on-prem database you'd plan it in advance and do it after hours. With RDS you can increase capacity for just that operation, reducing downtime. There are techniques to reduce the load too. You can create the new table structure on the side and copy the existing data over, then rename the tables. [This article puts a view](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/partitioning-a-large-table-without-a-long-running-lock/) in front of the tables, hiding the switch

Comment: This isn't exactly a programming question. It would be (far) better to post this at https://dba.stackexchange.com People here may know about handling big database. For DBAs though, that's their actual job. I'd bet there are several people there that had to handle big data deletions in Postgres and even RDS multiple times already. There. may be AWS tools for just that job.

Comment: As the answer shows, a typical solution is to delete batches of rows in a loop. This is one of the few good uses for looping.  In the end, you pay the same overall cost but the system doesn't freeze. At 100M rows though, it's time to partition

Comment: From dba.stackexchange.com [How to partition existing table in postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106014/how-to-partition-existing-table-in-postgres) The accepted answer shows creating a new partitioned table, copying the data to the new table then *swapping the tables by renaming them*. The last part just changes metadata so the downtime is minimal. With Pg. 10+'s partitioning there's no need for inheritance or triggers though.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to delete lots of rows based on their `created_at` values. And,  I guess your table has an `id` column which is the unique primary key.

What you do is delete a batch with a limited row count at a time, like this.

```
DELETE FROM yourtable
 WHERE id IN (
     SELECT id
       FROM yourtable
      WHERE created_at < '2020-11-01'
      LIMIT 1000
    )
```

(In my example we're deleting all the rows in the table created anytime before the end of October 2020.)

This deletes a batch of 1000 rows. You keep running this query until it deletes no rows.

This works because it doesn't take long to delete each batch, and each batch won't interfere too much with your production workload or your vacuum maintenance. It will be especially efficient if you have an index on the `created_at` column.

Delaying a few hundred milliseconds between batches is also wise, because you're even less likely to interfere with your production workflow.

Deleting a quarter-billion rows a thousand at a time will take a quarter-million batches. But that's OK, it's why programming was invented. This batch approach has worked very well for the places I have worked, for tables that weren't originally designed for easy cleanup.

Once you've deleted your huge backlog of old rows, then keeping up with it every day is much easier.

If you have to delete a huge number of rows every day, though, partitions are the way to go (as mentioned in the comments). But I suspect you'll need downtime to convert your table layout to use them. It's not a small job.

Comment: This depends on having an index on `created_at` to avoid a full table scan. There are several similar techniques to handle this though - eg copy the PKs to delete into a temporary table and use it with USING. This is still costly though, especially on RDS